# How to upload local RStudio Project to Github including commit history?

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I have a RStudio Project with a history of git commit history.
I would like to upload this Project incl. the git commit history to Github and see the commit history on Github.

I can create a new repo on Github and commit from RStudio, but this would not include
past commits i have locally.

**What i tried:**

- I can upload a RStudio Project / package. But (all?) the git files are in a hidden Folder (OS: Windows 10) and i cant upload this hidden Folder to Github (get a warning / error message "This file is hidden").
- Looked through https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-git-github.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need would be to:

- add an origin to your local repository referencing the new (empty) GitHub repository
- push

That is:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<you>/<newRepo>
git push -u origin master
# or
git push --mirror
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your GitHub url to the remote using the Terminal tab then push. https://articles.assembla.com/en/articles/1136998-how-to-add-a-new-remote-to-your-git-repo